# .net core - AppSettings.json or Systemvariables?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'am new to C#, .net-core etc.
I'am writing a small WebApi for our intranet and in this Api I have to store some variables (e.g. LDAP-Path or AdminUser and AdminUserPW (as decrypted string)).

So my question is:
Whats the best place to store this variables?
In appsettings.json or in the Systemvariables of the server?

Comment: Are they variables for the system (used by several other applications) or the application (nothing else cares)? It would seem likely it's the latter, so they shouldn't be system variables.

Comment: Only variables for this WebApi not for other applications. The variables are 1) ip of anoher specified server 2) ldap path 3) network_admin_user 4) password of the user but encrypted   so this was my question, are there any (security) issues to store this variables in appsettings.json?

Comment: Are you using Azure? In that/either case you can check out this excellent blog post by Scott Hanselman: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestPracticesForPrivateConfigDataAndConnectionStringsInConfigurationInASPNETAndAzure.aspx

Comment: No, i'm not using Azure for this. It is an Api for our intranet.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP-Path, database connection string, other configurable stuff always store inside WebApi configuration file, this is why it is. If it's just small WebApi (without a lot of strict security requirements). For the AdminUser is better to use a [Secret Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/migration/configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1.)

Systemvariables is more for share some specific path at File System to other apps or modules, and if another person installs new App on the server, he can easily use your variable or rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

1. Put your development environment values in appsettings.json.
2. Put your production values in the environment settings for the server.
3. You a syntax such as this to enable overrides:

   var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .Build();

This says "Load the config from the JSON file, then override any values I defined at the server level".

The advantage of this method is that you don't have to juggle configuration files between environments. While `appsettings.json` is over-written each time you deploy your code, the server level variables remain untouched and thus correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use appsettings.json for storing your variables. Appsettings.json comes in different flavours depending on your stage of coding:

1. Development
2. Staging
3. Testing
4. Prod

This will also help and you can use code like:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

}

if (env.IsProduction() || env.IsStaging() || env.IsEnvironment("Staging_2"))
{
    // do something here
}
```

You can also dependency inject IWebHostEnvironment via your Startup.

Passwords btw shouldnt be stored in plain text and Microsoft suggests secrets.json

See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows